# Selection Sort (swapping pointers rather than data)

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, linked-list

I've been trying to create a `selection sort` function to sort a `linked list` in ascending order by swapping pointers only, rather than the data/contents of the `nodes` since I think if there is a lot of data in each node, then it would require a large amount of temporary memories for swapping data.

The problem is that there is something wrong with my logic of swapping that I could not figure out. I still have some test cases that after swapping, the linked lists' nodes are lost since the pointers couldn't connect them together.

My logic is that there should be 2 main cases:
Case 1) When the two nodes are **adjacent** (next to each other)
Case 2) When the two nodes are **afar** (not adjacent)

I have to deal with the first node (head); thus, there should be **4 cases** = (2 for head or non-head) x (2 for adjacent or afar)

These are the two classes that construct my linked list

```cpp
template <class T>
class ListNode
{
public:
    T value;
    ListNode<T> *next;
    ListNode(T val)
    {
        value=val;
        next=nullptr;
    }
};
template <class T>
class Class_LinkedList
{
private:
    ListNode<T> *head;
public:
    /*****constructors + functions*****/
    void sort() {;}
}
```

This is the sorting function that I'm having troubles with

```cpp
    void sort()
    {
        /*******There are four cases for swapping********
         Case 1: First node (head) and Minimum Node are not adjacent
         Case 2: First node (head) and Minimum Node are adjacent
         (Case 3 and 4 are for non-head)
         Case 3: The two nodes are not adjacent
         Case 4: The two nodes are adjacent */

        if (head==nullptr)
            return;

        ListNode<T> * pre_startPtr = nullptr; //points to the node before the starting node (selection sort)
        ListNode<T> * pre_nodePtr = nullptr; //temporary pointer that points to the node before the temporary node for traversing
        ListNode<T> * pre_minNodePtr=nullptr; //points to the node before the minimum node
        //the prefix pre_ indicates these pointers point to previous nodes

        /********Dealing with head/the first node*********
         * Traverse once through the list to find the minimum node and swap it with the first node
        **********************************/

        pre_minNodePtr=head;
        pre_nodePtr=head;

        while (pre_nodePtr->next!=nullptr)
        {
            if (pre_minNodePtr->next->value > pre_nodePtr->next->value)
            {
                pre_minNodePtr=pre_nodePtr;
            }
            pre_nodePtr=pre_nodePtr->next;
        }
        if (pre_minNodePtr->next->value < head->value) //if there is a value less than head value, then swap
        {
            //Case 1: First node (head) and Minimum Node are not adjacent

            if (head!=pre_minNodePtr)
            {
                ListNode <T> * temp;
                temp=head;
                head=pre_minNodePtr->next;
                pre_minNodePtr->next=head;
                temp=head->next;
                head->next=pre_minNodePtr->next->next;
                pre_minNodePtr->next->next=temp;
            }
            //Case 2: First node (head) and Minimum Node are adjacent
            else //if (head==pre_minNodePtr)
            {
                head=pre_minNodePtr->next;
                pre_minNodePtr->next=head->next;
                head->next=pre_minNodePtr;
            }
        }

        /************Dealing with the list after the first node**************/

        pre_startPtr=head; //starting node = the second node (the node after head)

        while (pre_startPtr->next!=nullptr)
        {

            pre_minNodePtr=pre_startPtr;
            pre_nodePtr=pre_startPtr->next;

            while (pre_nodePtr->next!=nullptr)
            {
                if (pre_minNodePtr->next->value > pre_nodePtr->next->value)
                {
                    pre_minNodePtr=pre_nodePtr;
                }
                pre_nodePtr=pre_nodePtr->next;
            }
            //swap nodes if there is a value less than that of the starting node
            if (pre_minNodePtr->next->value < pre_startPtr->next->value)
            {
                //Case 3: The two nodes are not adjacent
                if (pre_startPtr->next!=pre_minNodePtr)
                {
                    ListNode<T> * temp;
                    temp = pre_startPtr->next;
                    pre_startPtr->next=pre_minNodePtr->next;
                    pre_minNodePtr->next=temp;
                    temp = pre_startPtr->next->next;
                    pre_startPtr->next->next = pre_minNodePtr->next->next;
                    pre_minNodePtr->next->next = temp;
                }
                //Case 4: The two nodes are adjacent
                else //if (pre_startPtr->next==pre_minNodePtr)
                {
                    pre_startPtr->next=pre_minNodePtr->next;
                    pre_minNodePtr->next=pre_startPtr->next->next;
                    pre_startPtr->next->next=pre_minNodePtr;
                }
            }
            //starting node = the next node
            pre_startPtr=pre_startPtr->next;
        }
    }
```

Comment: First off, it's good that you are swapping pointers instead of data, because that is the ideal way to go about selection sort. Secondly, did you try using a debugger? If not, then this is a good time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Also, usually, the selection sort function should be named aptly as `selecSort` or the likes, and should Ideally take the linked list as an argument. Please change your naming convention too (Class_LinkedList) is really not welcome in cpp land :)

Comment: Thank you. I honestly don't know how to use a debugger; I'll watch youtube videos to know how to use it on Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Solved.
There is a mistake in my code that I didn't notice at first.
It is when swapping pre_minNodePtr->next with head I assigned pre_minNodePtr->next with head instead of temp (temporary value of head since head has already changed).

Incorrect line:

```
pre_minNodePtr->next=head;
```

should be fixed to

```
pre_minNodePtr->next=temp;
```